# What did Dumbledore do with his old wand?

Tags: harry-potter, albus-dumbledore

In the biography of Dumbledore (by Rita Skeeter) it is said that Dumbledore finally decided to confront his one time friend Gellert Grindelwald, who at the time was powerful and was in possession of the Elder Wand.

After Dumbledore defeated him in their famous duel, Dumbledore claimed his wand, the mythical Elder Wand and stopped using his old wand.

**So what did he do with his old wand?**

Comment: My guess would be "at the bottom of a drawer somewhere".

Comment: The other question does not seem to have an answer for what happened to his wand, just speculations about what it was made of

Comment: Yes, the Elder Wand was made from the hair of a Thestral. But I'm still impatient for an answer to the main question.

Comment: @Richard Knowing Dumbledore, it was invariably a sock drawer.

Comment: @sandysands - There's no answer in canon. You'll likely need to wait until a Pottermore update or maybe contact JKR personally to ask.

Comment: @Zibbobz, in a sock in the sock drawer.

Comment: @mikeazo And the wand core is made of socks.

Comment: So that's what this thing Uncle Al left me is...

Comment: He uses it as a knitting needle. No joke.

Comment: Good question... It could have been destroyed when Dumbledore and Grindelwald dueled, due to the fact that Grindelwald had the Elder Wand; or he could have given it to one of his peers throughout his professor years; or he may still have it in case somebody were to win the Elder Wand back - he would have a backup.

Comment: So, Dumbledore beat the Elder Wand and in the process lost his wand to the Elder Wand ? And even though wands can be handed out, the WAND chooses the Wizard, not the vice versa. Knowing this, no Hogwarts teacher would want to be in that position of receiving even Dumbledore's old wand. See what happened to Neville in the first 5 years when he used his dad's old wand !

Answer (score 3):

Having the Elder Wand, he would still have his old wand that 'chose' him. When Harry, Ron and Hermione had won wands, they didn't discard origionals, just in case.

The Elder Wand appears to have perfect allegiance, but Dumbledore is smart and wouldn't simply discard his origional wand, just in case it turned out to be needed, either due to the Elder malfunctioning, or being lost to another in a non-fatal way (which is what happened, right before Snape killed him).